# Кодировка Visual Studio 2012

Tags: кодировка, visual-studio, c++

Собираю проект, который содержит ошибку. Вместо описания ошибки появляется:

```
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: ёё√ыър эр эхЁрчЁх°хээ√щ тэх°эшщ ёшьтюы _main т ЇєэъЎшш ___tmainCRTStartup
1>c:\users\gek0n\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TestReverse\Debug\TestReverse.exe : fatal error LNK1120: эхЁрчЁх°хээ√ї тэх°эшї ¤ыхьхэЄют: 1
```

Что это может быть, как это настроить (чтобы кодировка была нормальная английская или русская)?

Comment: Не совсем по теме, но если есть сложности с чтение такого текста, то можно воспользоваться некоторыми сервисами по декодирования текста подобного вида. Например charset.ru

Answer (score 5):

LNK1120 говорит что у вас есть одна ошибка при линковке.

По данным LNK2019 (c MSDN):

- Проблемы при встраивании функций
- Автоматические переменные (область видимости функции)
- Отсутствует тело функции или переменная

конкретно у Вас - проблема с main-функцией, хорошо бы увидеть код main'a и настройки среды в проекте (SUBSYSTEM в Linker->System если не ошибаюсь, там WINDOWS, CONSOLE и так далее)

Answer (score -2):

Чтобы текст ошибок отображался правильно в русскоязычной студии, нужно подключить библиотеку "clocale" и прописать в коде "setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");".

Comment: Можно немножко поподробнее? Насколько я знаю `setlocale()` настраивает вывод в консоль моего приложения, но не самой студии.